# The complement of a cartesian product and the product topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I tried to prove that for topological spaces $X_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A$ for the product space $\prod_{\alpha} X_{\alpha}$ with the usual product topology if $A_{\alpha} \subseteq X_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in A$, then 
$$
 \overline{ \prod_{\alpha} A_{\alpha} } = \prod_{\alpha} \overline{ A_{\alpha} }
$$
where $\overline A_{\alpha}$ denotes the closure of $A_{\alpha}$. My proof relies on the axiom of choice, I will append it. But meanwhile there came another issue up my mind. Showing that $\prod_{\alpha} \overline{A_{\alpha}}$ is closed by establishing that its complement is open. But that means that it is a union of sets $\prod_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ with $U_{\alpha} \ne X_{\alpha}$ for only finitely many open subsets $U_{\alpha}$ of $X_{\alpha}$, more formally
$$
 \left[ \prod_{\alpha} \overline A_{\alpha} \right]^C = \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i
$$
where each $B_i = \prod_{\alpha} U^{(i)}_{\alpha}$ with $U_{\alpha}^{(i)} \ne X_{\alpha}$ for just finitely many $\alpha$. A first idea might be 
$$
  \left[ \prod_{\alpha} \overline A_{\alpha} \right]^C = \bigcup_{J \subseteq A, J \mbox{ finite}} B_J
$$
where $B_J = \prod_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ with $U_{\alpha} = \overline{A_{\alpha}}^C$ if $\alpha \in J$ and $U_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha}$ otherwise. But I think this is not working for if 
$$
 x \in \prod_{\alpha} \overline{A_{\alpha}}^C
$$
(i.e. $x \notin \overline A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in A$, might be expressed as $x \in B_J$ with $J = A$) then $x \notin \prod_{\alpha} \overline{A_{\alpha}}$, but it is not in any $B_J$ for $J$ a finite subset of $A$. So my question, is there any way to write
$$
 \prod_{\alpha} \overline A_{\alpha}
$$
as a union of open sets in the product topology? (surely it must be the case, but is there a way to explicitly give a formula for that)

For completeness, my proof of 
$$
\overline{ \prod_{\alpha} A_{\alpha} } = \prod_{\alpha} \overline{ A_{\alpha} }.
$$
Let $x \in \prod_{\alpha} \overline A_{\alpha}$ and let $U$ be an open basis set around $x$, i.e.
$$
 U = \prod_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}
$$
with finitely many open subsets $U_{\alpha} \ne X_{\alpha}$ and the rest $U_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha}$ and $x \in U$. Then because $x_{\alpha} \in U_{\alpha}$
for all $\alpha \in A$ and $x_{\alpha} \in \overline{A_{\alpha}}$ it is $U_{\alpha} \cap A_{\alpha} \ne \emptyset$ for all $\alpha \in A$. Therefore by the axiom of choice the set
$$
 \prod_{\alpha} (U_{\alpha} \cap A_{\alpha})
$$
is nonempty and so
$$
 U \cap \prod_{\alpha} A_{\alpha} = \prod_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} \cap \prod_{\alpha} A_{\alpha} = \prod_{\alpha} (U_{\alpha} \cap A_{\alpha})
$$
is nonempty too, and therefore $\overline{ \prod_{\alpha} A_{\alpha} } = \prod_{\alpha} \overline{ A_{\alpha} }$.

Comment: Ok, I did not read everything so let me do this as a comment. Let $p_\alpha\colon \prod_\beta X_\beta\to X_\alpha$ denote the projection. Then $\prod X_\alpha\setminus\prod \overline{A_\alpha}=\bigcup_\alpha p_\alpha^{-1}[X_\alpha\setminus\overline{A_\alpha}]$ is a union of open sets.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes, that's it, quite simple... furthermore my statement "$x \notin \prod_{\alpha} \overline{A_{\alpha}}$, but it is not in any $B_J$ for $J$ a finite subset of $A$." is wrong, of course if $J = \emptyset$ then $B_J = \prod_{\alpha} X_{\alpha}$ and surely contains everything. Seems to be I was just confused on a higher level ;) Would you mind to put your simple comment as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we denote projections by
\begin{align}
p_\alpha\colon \prod_\beta X_\beta&\to X_\alpha\\
x&\mapsto x_\alpha,
\end{align}
then 
$$\prod_\alpha\overline{A_\alpha}=\bigcap_\alpha p_\alpha^{-1}[\overline{A_\alpha}],$$
which shows that it is closed and hence already proves
$$\prod_\alpha\overline{A_\alpha}\supset\overline{\prod_\alpha A_\alpha}.$$
Taking complements we obtain
$$\prod_\alpha X_\alpha\setminus\prod_\alpha\overline{A_\alpha}=\bigcup_\alpha p_\alpha^{-1}[X_\alpha\setminus\overline{A_\alpha}],$$
which explicitly writes the complement as a union of sets which are elements of the usual subbasis of the product.